# Arrays.equals() and String.equals() always return false

Tags: java, client-server

This is a very confusing problem that I am encountering when using the equals() method from classes Array and String: the methods always return false. I have tested for whitespace, debugged for hours and I can't find a single fix. This is an encrypted server chat room. I will only post a snippet of the server, because I am guessing that will be the only problem, but if you want me to post other snippets of code or classes I will.
The server code snippet:

```
private void handlePassword() {
            try {
                out.println(encrypter.encrypted("Enter Password."));
                out.flush();
                char[] ep = null;
                ep = encrypter.decrypted(in.readLine()).toCharArray();
                boolean tr = true;
                if (ep.length == password.length)
                    for (int i = 0; i < ep.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print(ep[i]);
                        System.out.print(password[i]);
                        if (ep[i] == password[i]) {
                            tr = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                System.out.println("AHHHHHHHHHHHH! " + tr);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(ep) + "\\/"
                        + String.valueOf(password));
                System.out.println(Arrays.equals(ep, password));
                if (!Arrays.equals(ep, password)) {
                    out.println(encrypter.encrypted("Incorrect Password."));
                    out.flush();
                    handlePassword();
                } else {
                    out.println(encrypter.encrypted("Access Granted"));
                    out.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                reportError(e);
            }
        }
```

-Variable Clarification

```
out = PrintWriter
in = BufferedReader
encrypter = My Encrypting Class
char[] password = The Server Password
```

-Console Output

When not valid (Password: asdf) (Tried Password: hhhh):

```
AHHHHHHHHHHHH! true
[asdf] hhhh\/asdf
false
```

When Valid: (Password: asdf) (Tried Password: asdf):

```
AHHHHHHHHHHHH! true
[asdf] asdf\/asdf
false
```

I really can't see a single problem. Please explain why this is happening. I really can't tell.

Comment: Posting a few hundred lines of code really isn't helping your question. For what inputs are you experiencing this problem?

Comment: Can you point out here exactly are you getting the problem?

Comment: You posted way too much code. It's better to isolate the problem with a simplified example.

Comment: That method is the main part of the code, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your output

`AHHHHHHHHHHHH! true
[asdf] asdf\/asdf
false`

ep = "[asdf] asdf" and password = "asdf", and Arrays.equals(ep, password) return false in that case

I see, that this block of code is not working:

`if (ep.length == password.length)
    for (int i = 0; i < ep.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(ep[i]);
       System.out.print(password[i]);
       if (ep[i] == password[i]) {
           tr = false;
           break;
       }
       System.out.println();
    }`

Maybe this line of code

`encrypter.decrypted(in.readLine()).toCharArray();`

return not "asdf"?

Comment: I just noticed that a few seconds ago, but making the chat room you are used to seeing the [username] prefix in front of the name and it confuses you. Thanks though!